# How to force a dll to be be accessible at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dll

In the following code, System.Core.dll is not outputted from the compilation because there are no LINQ extension methods used in the .cs file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqTestFramework
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "David" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

However, during debug I'd like to be able to call LINQ extension methods on the `dict` object and view the result in the Watch window.

How can I force System.Core.dll to be included after compilation so that I can have access to LINQ extension methods during debug?

**Update:**

I've tried including code that does use LINQ. What I've found is that this does include System.Core.dll in the compilation output, however the code is still unavailable at run time:

[image]

I had to uncomment out that line which references the code that uses Linq, in order to be able to use Linq extension methods during debug in the Watch window.

Is there any way to access Linq extension methods during debug without having to reference code that uses Linq extension methods?

Comment: Use Assembly.Load, then you can use it in debug window.

Comment: @eocron that works when System.Core.dll is included in the compilation output. However for that I need to write code (doesn't have to be called), that uses Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this extension when want to explicitly reference an assembly:

```
public static class AssemblyReference
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Installs reference to assembly in which specified type resides.
    /// It will be copied on build even in release mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static void Install<T>()
    {

    }
}
```

Then you can use an assembly load. The easiest of course is just to invoke something from namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method that DOES use Linq.  It doesn't have to be actually called by your code, just referenced.

Comment: I realised that that will include System.Core.dll in the output, however the extension methods are still unavailable during debug (see my updated question).

Comment: Include an extension function in your unused method.

Comment: Do you mean a Linq extension method? I have already included that in that unused method, I'm using Where().

Comment: TBH If this doesn't work then why not put a line in the actual code that does something non-destructuve Linq just after main.